# Check numbers in between 2 integers

Tags: java, loops, netbeans, integer

I am doing revision for my upcoming Java test, and I am stuck at a part and I am unable to solve it.

Q: Take in 2 Integer, from Int A to Int B, display X if X is divisible by 6 OR 5 but not both, and print a new line after every 10 numbers.

Below is my current code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int numOne = sc.nextInt();
    int numTwo = sc.nextInt();
    int line = 1;

    while (numTwo > numOne) {

        if (line%11==0){
            System.out.println("");
        }

        if ((numOne % 5 == 0) && (numOne % 6 != 0)) {
            System.out.print(numOne + " ");
            line++;
        }
        if ((numOne % 6 == 0) && (numOne % 5 != 0)) {
            System.out.print(numOne + " ");
            line++;
        }
    }
    numOne++;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change code to

```
while (numTwo > numOne) {

        if (line%11==0){
            System.out.println("");
        }

        if ((numOne % 5 == 0) && (numOne % 6 != 0)) {
            System.out.print(numOne + " ");
            line++;
        }
        if ((numOne % 6 == 0) && (numOne % 5 != 0)) {
            System.out.print(numOne + " ");
            line++;
        }
      numOne++;
    }
```

Move `numOne++;` inside loop. You not changing any variable inside loop so you will get an infinite loop

Answer (score 2):

Your code gives an infinite loop because `numOne` is incremented **outside** the while loop. Just move it inside, and it seems to work correctly.

Comment: thank you! i did not realize that I left the increment outside

Answer (score 1):

You're increment is outside the while loop. You need to increment numOne at the end of the loop body.

Currently you have an infinite loop. As numOne never changes, numTwo is always greater than numOne.

Also use Exclusive OR `^`, it would make this question a lot simpler:
http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/java-questions/xor-in-java/

```
while (numTwo > numOne) {

    if (line%11==0){
        System.out.println("");
    }

    if ((numOne % 5 == 0) && (numOne % 6 != 0)) {
        System.out.print(numOne + " ");
        line++;
    }
    if ((numOne % 6 == 0) && (numOne % 5 != 0)) {
        System.out.print(numOne + " ");
        line++;
    }
    numOne++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also write:

```
if ((numOne % 5 == 0 || numOne % 6 == 0) && numOne % 30 != 0)
```